# Defining a list to use in the body of a for loop (tikzpicture)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am making a drawing with tikzpicture. A part of it is just drawing a line with nodes:

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,10}{  
     \draw[->-, very thick,red] (\x,0) -- (\x+1,0);
     \filldraw[yellow] (\x,0) circle (2.5pt);
}
```

Now I would like to name my nodes. Is there a way to define some kind of list and then call this list from the body of the for loop? I thought of something like this:

```
List= \{$1$, $w$, $tb$, etc\};
\foreach \x in {0,...,10}{  
         \draw[->-, very thick,red] (\x,0) -- (\x+1,0);
         \filldraw[yellow] (\x,0) circle (2.5pt) node[below,black]{List[\x]};
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array operations are explained [in the manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#subsection.94.2).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand*\List{{"$1$", "$w$", "$tb$"}}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,2}{  
    \draw[->, very thick,red] (\x,0) -- (\x+1,0);
    \filldraw[yellow] (\x,0) circle (2.5pt) node[below,black]{\strut\pgfmathprint{\List[\x]}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect exactly what I needed.

Comment: Keep in mind that this can be inconvenient. If you want to add a node you must also remember to extend the range of the loop by one. This step is omitted in both Steven's and my (the second) method.

Answer (score 3):

The `listofitems` package can help.  Then, a `\foreachitem` loop can be employed in lieu of a `\foreach` loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,listofitems}

\begin{document}
\readlist*\List{$1$, $w$, $tb$, etc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreachitem\x\in\List[]{  
     \ifnum\xcnt=\listlen\List[]\relax\else
       \draw[-, very thick,red] (\xcnt,0) -- (\xcnt+1,0);\fi
     \filldraw[yellow] (\xcnt,0) circle (2.5pt) node[below,black]{\strut\x};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, I might use this the future.

Answer (score 3):

Although I think that Steven's answer is superior, here's my take on your problem. I think that code is easier to understand but you have to define two variables.

Plus I've centered the arrow as I think that you wanted to achieve this with your non-existing arrow tip `->-`, isn't it?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[decoration = {
            markings,
            mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}
        }]
        
        \foreach \x/\y in {
                0/$1$,
                1/$w$,
                2/$tb$,
                3/etc
            }{  
             \draw[postaction={decorate}, very thick,red] (\x,0) -- (\x+1,0);
             \filldraw[yellow] (\x,0) circle (2.5pt) node[below,black]{\strut\y};
        }
        
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Edit

I just thought of another possibility which is even more simple. You can access the index if the `\foreach` with the `[count = \i]` option. This is in fact the same thing Steven has proposed, but you don't need to load a new package and thus dealing with that new syntax or possible compatibility issues.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[decoration = {
            markings,
            mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow{>}}
        }]
        
        \foreach \x [count=\i] in {
                $1$,
                $w$,
                $tb$,
                etc
            }{  
             \draw[postaction={decorate}, very thick,red] (\i,0) -- (\i+1,0);
             \filldraw[yellow] (\i,0) circle (2.5pt) node[below,black]{\strut\x};
        }
        
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This kind of for loop indexing looks very useful indeed. Thx for the suggestion!

Comment: You're welcome!